# FPDF - save marathi data into fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, fpdf

I am getting marathi value in an array. I want to print it in PDF using FPDF. But all i am getting is "à¤‡à¤¸à¤°à¥‰à¤¯à"

I am using utf8 charset which supports Marathi font and many other. But its also not working well.

Please give me the solution to save marathi data in PDF using FPDF.

Sample marathi data(if you want it for testing purpose) - खालीलपैकी कोणते नाटके हर्षवर्धानाने लिहिली

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of tFPDF? http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Comment: @Ollie Jones I saw tFPDF. I tried to run with it. But its also generating square like [][][][][]

Comment: @Ollie Jones If i copy these squares and paste it somewhere else, it gives me what i want. Its just not generating in PDF.

Comment: Those squares -- they're called replacement glyphs -- mean your pdf file does not contain the correct codepoints from the font. Have you instructed tpdf to load the font with glyphs for your Marathi codepoints?

Comment: @Ollie Jones No. Frankly speaking, i didnt get what you asked for. But I didnt do anything like that.

Can you please tell me how to do it to get Marathi font..?

Comment: Marked as dup -- see "Mojibake" in that Q&A.